# Filling gaps in characters using cv2

Tags: python, ocr, opencv

I have an image file with text which I want to extract using OCR.
But it has a diagonal overlapping line of text over it (top right), like [image: this].
I remove this line using,

```
  image = cv2.imread(image_path)

  image = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

  image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5, 5), 0)

  image = cv2.threshold(image, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1] # 100 here as the diagonal line is grey
```

This results in an image like, [image: this].

Notice the thick characters for **shear stress**, it is one of the regions where the diagonal line overlapped.
Now I apply OCR. However, the previous steps remove some pixels. For instance, the **e** in **edge dislocation** is not complete.

This results in poor results like, "edve dislocation". I tried erosion and dilation but with no significant improvement.

Is there any way to fill up the holes in characters?

Is there any way to reduce thickness of the characters which overlap with the diagonal line?

Comment: Try adaptive thresholding in place of your binary thresholding. That should give you just the outline of the diagonal lettering and thus cause less modification on the text you want to extract.

Comment: You can also just try changing the value of the gray diagonal letters to white.

Answer (score 0):

Since in Images if you see, we can represent dark areas(Black) from 2^0 = 0 to light areas(white) 2^8 = 256 .
So one thing which you can try (I'm also not sure on this):
`img = cv2.imread(image_path,0)
new_img = img.copy()
new_img[new_img<=230] = 0 ## just try to change that 230 value to anywhere b/w 150 to 230`

then try to use OCR to check if it really worked.

-- apply this on result of your image after removing overlapping